# Will every line in a program(except variable declarations) ultimately use atleast one system call?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, operating-system, system-calls

I was thinking about system calls and code that we write! Lets say I have a program like below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a=0,b=2,c;
   c=a+b;
   printf("The value of c is %d", c);
   return 0;
}
```

Lets take the case of c = a+b; if it was c++ compiler, then i beleive there would be a call to operator+() function. The compiler ofcourse might optimize it by replacing it with the actual code that performs addition rather than a function call within an assembly code.

And printf will have to use system call in order to write it to different hardware buffers. So i beleive most of the api's provided by the language would use system call to accomplish the function.. I am not sure if my understanding is correct. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Define 'system call' before thinking further.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, not at all. I'm unsure if you have your definition of a system call correct. Stealing a definition from Wikipedia:

> In computing, a system call is how a program requests a service from an operating system's kernel.

This means that the kinds of operations that result in system calls are I/O, timing, etc -- *not* math, assignments, (most) memory assignments, ...

Even `malloc()` is usually implemented so you don't always need a system call. In general: *only actions that affect or interact with the program's **surrounding enviroment*** require a system call. Registers, program variables, etc. do not count as part of the surrounding environment.

Comment: +1 clear answer that avoids being misleading while not going into unnecessary detail.

Comment: Definition from wikipedia is quite broad, and therefore it is not always as simple as one might think. For example most of modern operating systems use virtual memory, so even accesing process'es own memory (variable assignment) might require calling some operating system functions (indirectly and from point of view of a program invisibly, but still) eg. in case memory page needs to be swapped into actual RAM. I think this also qualifies as service from an operating system, although that's not how we usually understand system call.

Comment: @j_kubik: by that logic, even `goto` can do this: code can also be swapped out. I don't think it's productive to consider memory access a service request.

Comment: @j_kubik a 'system call' is where the program *requests* a system service, i.e. *calls* the *system.* Most of what you have described is accomplished via interrupts such as page faults, which are not requests.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Ethereal's answer, even if you mean "call" (as in to a function) rather than "system call" the answer is still no.  For example, `c=a+b` is likely to generate inline assembly similar to the following pseudo-assembly:

```
mov reg1, [a]
mov reg2, [b]
add reg1, reg2
mov [c], reg1
```

No calls needed!